# Have we calculated the electric dipole moment of ammonia, or energy difference, from theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

In the [Feynman Lectures on Physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_09.html#Ch9-S2), Feynman says nobody has calculated the frequency of the ammonia maser, which is related to the Hamiltonian for the nitrogen atom to "flip" to the other side of the hydrogens, from theory.  Same for the electric dipole moment.  Of course, that was over 50 years ago, before modern computing.  Is it that hard to do now?  Ammonia is $\mathrm{NH}_3$, so 10 electrons.  Can we do that through numerical computation now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easily doable nowadays. One such example is

> One‐Center Basis Set SCF MO's. II. NH$_3$, NH$_4^+$, PH$_3$, PH$_4^+$. R Moccia. [*J. Chem. Phys.* **40**, (2004)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1725490).

but you can find plenty with some shallow Google Scholar searches. Ten electrons was a hard problem in the sixties, but we have many orders of magnitude more computing power than was available at the time, plus plenty of algorithmic improvements (such as e.g. things as basic as density functional theory, whose foundation was published pretty much concurrently with the Feynman lectures).

Comment: Thanks!  Interesting that some of the values didn't agree with experiment too well.

Comment: That's one specific example of one specific method. It should definitely be possible to get everything just right, but it's a question of how much you care about it, for how many molecules you want to do it, and how much compost muscle and fibre you have. Don't read too much into that discrepancy unless it's very widespread in the literature.

Comment: Oh, I assume it's a limitation of the computational technique, and has no doubt been improved since then, or even around then with a different technique.  I just thought it was interesting that these things are so hard to compute that even a computer from a decade ago couldn't agree with experiment.  I doubt it's exposing a discrepancy between theory and practice.